# C++ Multithreading exception when not calling Thread.join()

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, join

I have a really simple program that is giving me an exception I don't understand.  I have a C++ app written in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Desktop.

I created a multithreaded application where I have 2 threads, one calls one person class, the other calls another car class.

When I use the thread.join() I don't get the exception, but I don't get the desired output.  When I comment out the thread.join() I get the exception, but I also get the desired output.

The exception being:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rITL.png)

I'm just trying to have two threads execute and process at the same time.  Both the person and car class has a method invoked that repeats 10 times with a thread sleep and all it does is print a string "started walking" for the person class and "started driving" for the car class and the main thread just has "Main waiting..."

So the output of the program is:

```
started walking
started driving
started walking
started driving
main waiting...
started walking
started driving
started walking
started driving
main waiting...
```

etc. which is what I want.

If I uncomment the join method I get this output:

```
started walking
started walking
(repeat 8 more times)
started driving 
started driving
(repeat 8 more times)
Main waiting..
Main waiting..
(repeat 8 more times)
```

and this is not what I want.

How can I have this app execute without that exception without using the join() method?

As an FYI, here's the sample code I created below:

Here's the main method that starts the program.

```
include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include "person.h"
#include "car.h"

int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;

int main()
{
    person p1;
    thread t1(&person::startWalking, p1);
    if(t1.joinable())
    {
        //t1.join();
    }

    car c1;
    thread t2(&car::startDriving, c1);
    if(t2.joinable())
    {
        //t2.join();
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        std::cout<<"Main waiting...\n";//<<std::endl;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the person.cpp file:

```
#include "person.h"
person::person(void)
{
}
person::~person(void)
{
}
void person::startWalking()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        cout<<"Started Walking.\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}

void person::stopWalking()
{
    cout<<"Stopped Walking.\n";
}
```

Here's the car.cpp file:

```
#include "car.h"

using namespace std;

car::car(void)
{
}
car::~car(void)
{
}
void car::startDriving()
{
    for(int x = 0; x< 10; x++)
    {
        std::cout<<"started driving\n.";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation for `std::thread::join`.

Comment: I have and it doesn't really say what would cause the exception that I pasted. The site cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join mentions that invoking the join() method "This blocks the execution of the thread that calls this function until the function called on construction returns (if it hasn't yet)."  The thing is I don't want the invoked thread to block the thread that called it.  I want them to run simultaneously, but I get this exception.

Comment: I must admit I feel a little sheepish right now.  I looked online and saw that calling the thread.detach() method gives me the output I want and it doesn't give an exception either.  I blame myself for not looking good enough online before posting this question.

Comment: Don't use pictures for exception texts, that makes it impossible to search for it. Oh, and search for that text, it will probably reveal what's wrong and where in the documentation to find info about it. Lastly, reduce your code to a minimal but complete example; Without it, it is by definition off-topic.

Comment: `std::thread::detach` is not the right solution here. When you're programming with threads, hacking code until it seems to work is absolutely the wrong approach. You need to join both threads, but not until they've **both** been launched. Once you've done that, you don't need the sleep call. And you don't need to check whether a newly-launched thread is joinable. It is.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the [document](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/~thread/) reads that `If the thread is joinable when destroyed, terminate() is called.`, so if you comment the thread.join() and the `main` function finished, the thread must call destructor and it will call `terminate`, and `terminate` is `abort` here, so you got an exception!

If you uncomment thread.join(), [join](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/) method `returns when the thread execution has completed.` so you cannot get the excepted answer.

**Advice:**

move

```
if(t1.joinable())
{
    t1.join();
}
```

and

```
if(t2.joinable())
{
    t2.join();
}
```

before `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));`. You can see those three threads exec the same time, but you cannot get the result you want as well, because `t1` and `t2` sleep 1 second, so the main thread will print the `Main waiting...` very quickly. So you should comment the `sleep` in `t1` and `t2` or add the same sleep time to each loop in `for` of main.

*Hint*: Those three thread will compete and the output buffer will be filled randomly, so the output will be unpredictable, you can add a mutex to  ensure the output is readable.

Here is my code to reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mMutex;

class person {
public:
    void startWalking()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            mMutex.lock();
            std::cout<< "Started Walking.\n";
            mMutex.unlock();
            //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        }
    }
};

class car {
public:
    void startDriving()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x< 10; x++)
        {
            mMutex.lock();
            std::cout <<"Started driving.\n";
            mMutex.unlock();
            //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    person p1;
    std::thread t1(&person::startWalking, p1);

    car c1;
    std::thread t2(&car::startDriving, c1);

    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        mMutex.lock();
        std::cout <<"Main waiting...\n";
        mMutex.unlock();
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    return 0;
}
```